# Bash printf string replacement from file does not account for quotes

Tags: bash, printf

I want to take an input file which has two columns and pass it to printf using command substitution:

`cat <(printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' $(< input.txt) )`

**input.txt**

```
some_variable one
some_other_var 2
different_var "hello"
var_after_newlines 18
{{hello}} " this is just a string surrounded by space "
{bello} "this is just a string"
cello "#string with a comment in it"
```

I figured it would nicely replace the %s with each column respectively, but this isn't the case for the stringy bits. Those are interpreted as individual strings seperated by space, compare:

Expectation:

```
s/some_variable/one/g
s/some_other_var/2/g
s/different_var/hello/g
s/var_after_newlines/18/g
s/{{hello}}/ this is just a string surrounded by space /g
s/{bello}/this is just a string/g
s/cello/#string with a comment in it/g
```

Reality:

```
s/some_variable/one/g
s/some_other_var/2/g
s/different_var/"hello"/g
s/var_after_newlines/18/g
s/{{hello}}/"/g
s/this/is/g
s/just/a/g
s/string/surrounded/g
s/by/space/g
s/"/{bello}/g
s/"this/is/g
s/just/a/g
s/string"/cello/g
s/"#string/with/g
s/a/comment/g
s/in/it"/g
```

As we can see the printf repetition behaviour carries on over multiple lines fed from input.txt I think.

I did my own testing to see how printf would behave and had this result:

```
$ printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' abc "def ghi"
s/abc/def ghi/g
```

So this works. But apparently when I'm reading from a file the string is somehow not interpreted as being one big chunk but multiple parts.

I'm using git bash on Windows so CRLF could get in the way, but I doubt it honestly. What else could cause this behaviour and how do I fix it?

Comment: Quoting characters are only special when they are embedded in the original command. For example, `a='"foo"'; echo $a` prints `"foo"`, not `foo`.

Comment: This might shed some light about the use of `$(<...)` https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor , You can read the file line-by-line https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 or use the right tool manipulate/edit stream or text. like `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: The problem isn't with `printf`, it's with the word-splitting performed on `$(< input.txt)` before it's passed to `printf`. Basically, the word-splitting and wildcard expansion performed on unquoted command substitutions (and variable references, etc) is fundamentally stupid, and you should find some other way to break the file into lines and fields.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the spaces in input.txt, you need something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
perl -ne 'print "s/$1/$2/g\n" if (/(\S+) "?(..*?)"?$/)' input.txt
```